# Cookie from response doesn't get set in time for navigation within React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, cookies, react-router

I have React component with a method handling authentication.

Component code

```
handleAuthentication(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   try {
       createAuth();
       this.props.history.push("/");
   } catch(e) {
       // error handling
   }
}
```

Service calls

```
export function createAuth() {
    call("auth");
}

async function call() {
    await Axios.post("/" + operation, data)
        .catch(r => // error handling)
        .then(r => // success handling)
}
```

Route logic

```
function renderProtectedComponent(Component, props) {
    return Cookies.get("auth") ? <Component {...props} />: <CreateProfileWithRouter />; 
}
```

If I get rid of the `this.props.history.push("/");`, the auth cookie does get populated.

With `this.props.history.push("/");`, the route logic gets hit, but the auth cookie doesn't get set (quick enough?), on the first navigation attempt, for the route logic to return the `<Component {...props} />`. On subsequent attempts, I get `<Component {...props} />`.

I'm wondering what I'm missing to make it so that the auth cookie is set, before the route logic is called.

Comment: is `createAuth()` the same as `createPermanentAuth()`?

Comment: @Anthony yes, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `createAuth()` is asynchronous, meaning the the call to `this.props.history.push('/')` will likely be executed before `createAuth()` finishes. I think you could:

change `createAuth()` to

```
return call('auth')
```

and then mark `handleAuthentication` as `async` and `await` the call to `createAuth()` i.e.

```
async handleAuthentication(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   try {
       await createAuth();
       this.props.history.push("/");
   } catch(e) {
       // error handling
   }
}
```